# How to connect to Mysql from C# as MT4 dll?

Tags: c#, mysql, dll, connection, mt4

I am new to C#. I want to connect to Mysql Database from MT4 using DLL. I found how to create MT4 dll using C# here : http://vb6-to-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/04/code-to-export-c-dll-to-metatrader.html   , and how to connect to Mysql database using C# here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp .

How to combine both to connect to Mysql from MT4 ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us a bit more effort before you will get an answer.  All you have provided is a brief description and some links...

Answer (score 0):

MT4 is C++ not C#. In fact by using C# you are complicating things unnecessarily because you need to marshall the datatypes between the two languages. Also you didn't specify what part of mt4 you want to connect. I assume it's the client terminal via an expert advisor's dll. The simplest way is to write a dll using C++ which will export the methods you need for writing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer C# over MQL a viable option is to use a framework that lets you code a complete EA using C#. For example this bridge: [NQuotes : C# API for MetaTrader](http://www.nquotes.net/) let's you doing that. Then you can use your MySQL tutorial as it is.